# Adding ColorSpace to resources causes the stream to close

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am trying very simple steps to add colorspace to resources using PDFBOX version 2.0.7, but it is not working.

I have PDF "pdf1.pdf", I am reading the colorspaces from this file and adding them to HashMap, then I am creating new resources and trying to add the colorspaces to the newly created resources. But it is not working

So the first Step, I read the colorSpaces from the sourcePdf file and add them to HashMap:

```
    seperationColors = new HashMap<COSName, PDColorSpace>();
    PDDocument sourcePdfFile = null;
    try {
        sourcePdfFile = PDDocument.load(new FileInputStream(new File(pdfPath)));
        PDPage page = sourcePdfFile.getPages().get(0);
        page.getContents();
        for (COSName name : page.getResources().getColorSpaceNames()) {
            PDColor color = page.getResources().getColorSpace(name).getInitialColor();
            if (color.getColorSpace() instanceof PDSeparation) {
                seperationColors.put(name, page.getResources().getColorSpace(name));
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (sourcePdfFile != null)
            try {
                sourcePdfFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                sourcePdfFile = null;
            }
    }
}
```

Then, at later stages in the code, I want to create new PDF document, and add the colorSpaces from the source Pdf to the new one.

```
        PDResources newResources = new PDResources();
        PDColorSpace colorSpace = originalDocumentColorSpaces.values().iterator().next();
        newResources.add(colorSpace);
```

newResources will have the error: COSDictionary{COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?}
after the add operation (line 3)

colorSpace is of type PDSeperation.

Any clue?

Comment: please edit your question to include the version. And please include a bit more code. And clarify what you mean with "after the add operation" - did you close the source file?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Hi Tilman, I edited the question, infact, after I posted the question, I went back to the code and kept the source file open, and it worked.
The idea I am trying to achieve is: save colorspace in an arraylist / hashmap from PDF1, then add that colorspaces into new document in later code. But it turned out that I need to keep PDF1 open, is there a method to clone the colorspaces and save them into an arraylist for later use.

Comment: There is the `PDFCloneUtility` class but it will go non-public in 3.0. I'd recommend that you keep what you did, i.e. keep track of open documents and not close too early. Consider answering the question yourself.